# CMAKE in Visual Studio seems to recognize header files but fail to build anyway

Tags: c, visual-studio, cmake

I know this is a common question, but I've already lost two days to this.

I have a ***VERY*** basic cmake project in visual studio 2019, that will eventually need to compile for Linux and Windows, but right now I cannot get beyond simple compiler errors.

I have my project directory(as provided by visual studio) as follows

```
Solution
|-Project
| |-Includes
| | |-defines.h
| | |-lib.h
| | |-lib.c 
| |-main.c
| |-CMakeLists.txt
|-CMakeLists.txt
|-CMakeSettings.json
```

the problem that occurs is, all functions in all files autocomplete appropriately with intellisense, so something is going right. However, when I try to build(for any target) I get `undefined reference to {name}` for EVERY reference to anything in the lib.h and lib.c files.

The CMakeLists.txt is as below

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for LabJackStreamPortable, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

# Add source to this project's executable.
include_directories(Includes)
add_executable (Project "main.c")
# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.
```

nothing I've done with changing the include directory, or using  `target_include_directories` changes anything. I've gotten the project to build for all targets with basic include (stdlib, stdio, etc...) and build referencing basic #define constants from the `defines.h`. but any function housed in the lib.c file give errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undefined reference after using CMAKE to generate a makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46920289/undefined-reference-after-using-cmake-to-generate-a-makefile)

Comment: Do not *describe* the code and the error message. Instead, **show them** (add to the question post). Preferrably in a form of [mcve], so your problem could reproduced by others.A problem which cannot be reproduced is rarely can be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

From your example, you haven't specified `lib.c` anywhere, so this file will not be compiled. Therefore, if your `main.c` file references *anything* in `lib.c`, you will certainly receive errors.

If you want CMake to compile `lib.c` also, you need to list it explicitly as one of the source files:

```
add_executable (Project main.c Includes/lib.c)
```

Comment: the project statement is in the root list file. I left out the root file because that was pretty much the only thing in there.

Comment: All this did is make me get the same error for EVERYTHING in lib.c instead of only the ones used in main.c

Comment: @Whistler On your machine, does the `Includes` directory *actually* exist? Or is this just what is shown in the Visual Studio explorer window? Does the `lib.c` file actually reside in the `Includes` directory? Or is it a sibling to `main.c`? Along with these questions, it is tough to say what the remaining undefined reference errors might be without seeing the specific errors, or the C code. Please add this information to your question post.

Comment: I cant add code until tomorrow but, yes the folder is real. And as for the errors, imagine a normal c file. But every function definition give a an error that the function cant find a reference to...itself